# update real time in react and nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to achieve when user upload their profile image on website and it auto change the old profile picure into new profile picture instead user have to log out and log back in to make it works.

Here is my front end code base:

```
const UserCard = ({ picture, name, userEmail, isVerified, id, setPicture, setUser}) => {

      const [imageSelected, setImageSelected] = useState("");
    
      useEffect(() => {
        if (imageSelected !== '') {
          uploadImage();
        }
         
      }, [imageSelected]);
    
    
      const uploadImage = () => {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("file", imageSelected);
        formData.append("id", id);
    
        axios
          .post("/api/v1/users/upload/image", formData, {
            headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
          })
          .then((response) => {
            setPicture(response.data.data.imageUrl);
            setUser(prev => ({ ...prev, picture: response.data.data.imageUrl }));

          });
      };
      // End of Method
      const inputFile = useRef(null);
      const onButtonClick = () => {
        // `current` points to the mounted file input element
       inputFile.current.click();
      };
    
      return (
        <div className="avatar--icon_profile">
          <Card className="profile--card_container">
            <CardContent>
              {picture ? (
                <div>
                  <input
                    className="my_file"
                    type="file"
                    ref={inputFile}
                    onChange={(e) => setImageSelected(e.target.files[0])}
                  />
                    <div className="profile-image">                
                      <Avatar
                          src={picture}
                          alt="Avatar"
                          className="avatar--profile_image"
                          onClick={onButtonClick}
                      />
                      </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
```

and here is my backend router to send image from client to cloudinary (where I store all the images):

```
router.post('/upload/image', function (req, res, next) {

  const dUri = new Datauri();

  const dataUri = (req) => dUri.format(path.extname(req.name).toString(), req.data);

  if (req.files !== undefined && req.files !== null) {
    const { file, id } = req.files;

    const newFile = dataUri(file).content;
   
    cloudinary.uploader.upload(newFile)
      .then(result => {
        const imageUrl = result.url;
        const data = {id : req.body.id, imageUrl };
      updateAvatar(data);
      return res.status(200).json({ message: 'Success', data: { imageUrl } });
    }).catch(err =>  res.status(400).json({message:'Error', data: { err}}));
  } else {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Error' });
  }

});
```

How can I achieve it ?

Added GlobalState.js:

```
const GlobalState = (props) => {
  // User State -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  const [currentUser, setUser] = useState(props.serverUserData);

  // This method is passed through context to update currentUser
  const updateUser = (userData) => {
    setUser(userData);
  };

  // Modal State -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  const [isModalOpen, setModalOpenState] = useState(false);
  const [modalToDisplay, setModalToDisplay] = useState("signup");

  // This function will be provided to any function that needs to toggle the modal.
  const toggleModal = () => {
    // Take the previous state and flip it.
    setModalOpenState((prevState) => !prevState);
  };

  // This method is passed through context to update the next modal to open.
  const setModal = (name) => {
    // Take the passed in modal name and set state.
    setModalToDisplay(name);
  };

  // Loading State ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // NOT REACT STATE
  const [loading, setLoadingState] = useState(false);

  // This state will be used as messages in effects to refetch data.
  const [reloadThisData, setWhatToReload] = useState("");

  // User profile id for query ----------------------------------------------------------------
  const [userProfileId, setUserProfileId] = useState("");

  // Flag to determine if the header should change css style.  ----------------------------------------------------------------
  const [adjustBrightness, setAdjustBrightness] = useState(false);

  // This is the object passed to GlobalContext.Provider
  const providerValues = {
    isModalOpen,
    toggleModal,
    modalToDisplay,
    setModal,
    currentUser,
    updateUser,
    loading,
    setLoadingState,
    reloadThisData,
    setWhatToReload,
    userProfileId,
    setUserProfileId,
    adjustBrightness,
    setAdjustBrightness,
  };
  
  return (
    <GlobalContext.Provider value={providerValues}>
      {props.children}
    </GlobalContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default GlobalState;
```

Added console.log(currentUser):

```
{id: "a9aa869e-e28b-4a06-b5c7-88571d490e04", name: "nhan nguyen", email: "nhannguyen4119@gmail.com", publicId: "nh1615539696370", picture: "http://res.cloudinary.com/teammateme/image/upload/v1617073225/hvckrm6bklbpjk9njrlf.jpg", …}
email: "nhannguyen4119@gmail.com"
id: "a9aa869e-e28b-4a06-b5c7-88571d490e04"
isSessionValid: true
name: "nhan nguyen"
picture: "http://res.cloudinary.com/teammateme/image/upload/v1617073225/hvckrm6bklbpjk9njrlf.jpg"
publicId: "nh1615539696370"
__proto__: Object
```

Update my code after edit:

```
const UserProfile = () => {
  const appState = useContext(GlobalContext);
  const { currentUser, setUser } = appState;
  const { email, name, id } = currentUser;
  const [isVerified, setIsVerified] = useState(false);

  const [picture, setPicture] = useState(currentUser.picture);

  const checkVerificationData = () => {
    axios.get("/api/v1/profiles/profile").then((res) => {
      const { data } = res;   
      if (data.verifiedDT) {
        setIsVerified(data.verifiedDT);
      }
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    checkVerificationData();
  }, [isVerified]);


  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Grid item xs={12}
        container
        direction="row"
        justify="center"
        alignItems="center"
        spacing={4}>
        <Grid item>
          <Grid item>
            <UserCard
              picture={picture}
              setPicture={setPicture}
              userEmail={email}
              name={name}
              isVerified={isVerified}
              id={id}
              setUser={setUser}
            />
            <br />
          </Grid>
          <div>
            <Grid item>
              <div className="profile--layout_userInfo">
                <Grid item>
                  <UserInfo />
                </Grid>
              </div>
            </Grid>
          </div>
        </Grid>
        <div>
          <Grid item>
            <div className="profile--layout_ratings_reviews_block">
              <UserRatingsDetailed userEmail={email} />
            </div>
          </Grid>
        </div>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
};

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  let serverUserData = {};

  if (
    context.req.session.passport !== undefined &&
    context.req.session.passport.user !== undefined
  ) {
    const userPassportInfo = context.req.session.passport.user;
    const { id, name, email, publicId, picture } = userPassportInfo;
    const isSessionValid = context.req.isAuthenticated();

    serverUserData = {
      id,
      name,
      email,
      publicId,
      picture,
      isSessionValid,
    };
  }

  return { props: { serverUserData } };
}


UserProfile.propTypes = {
  serverUserData: PropTypes.object, 
};

export default UserProfile;
```

Comment: You mention log out and log in as the way to get the new profile picture to appear rather than a simple page refresh. Is this because you do the initial pull of the profile picture information during the login process?

Comment: @HenryEcker I dont get what u mean by initial pull ?

Comment: I guess my question is: how would you normally retrieve the user's profile picture? And is doing that procedure not an option at the end of your ```uploadImage``` function?

Comment: I retrieve the user's info by Context. I added my Context in the post

Comment: Then my recommendation would be to add something like a ```getUserProfileImage``` to your global context management, and call that after you upload the new image. Or since it appears you're returning the new url of the photo add a ```updateUserProfileLink``` and pass the new url to that.

Comment: So do I need to create a new context file or just add it in global State ?

Comment: I would just add a new method in your global state to update to the new image link.

Comment: @HenryEcker Thank you so much Henry. Could you write an sample code to help me get the idea... I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion from the comments in answer form is to create a manager similar to your other managers in the global context of your react application.

```
const GlobalState = (props) => {
    // Profile Image -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    const [currentProfileImage, setProfileImage] = useState(/*props.serverUserData.profileImage??*/);
    ...
};

export default GlobalState;
```

Don't forget to update your `providerValues` to include these new values.

Then, anywhere you use the profile image URI use the `currentProfileImage` variable from your context provider.

Lastly, when you upload your image to your server, and receive the new URI in the response use the `setProfileImage` function from global state to update the profile image in your global state.

```
const uploadImage = () => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", imageSelected);
    formData.append("id", id);

    axios.post("/api/v1/users/upload/image", formData, {
        headers: {"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"},
    }).then((response) => {
        GlobalState.setProfileImage(response.data.data.imageUrl);
    });
};
```

*I don't have a complete view of your program, and so this is my best guess of a reasonable way to implement your desired behaviour.

You'll need to update the initial state of the `useState` directive to reflect where in your `props` structure the profileImage URI is actually located, and you'll need to update the `GlobalState` placeholder to reflect however you are actually accessing your provided context.

Comment: I just added the console.log currentUser object in my post. Is that the object i need to put in my useState?

Comment: Either ```props.serverUserData.picture``` or ```currentUser.picture``` you're just looking to update the picture URI.

Comment: With this new information about your currentUser structure you could probably just use the existing hooks for user and use ```currentUser.picture``` and ```setUser(prev => ({...prev, picture:response.data.data.imageUrl}))```

Comment: I tried but still didn't work out

Comment: just updated all my code in post.

Comment: Can you help me with this problem. I really appreciate it @Henry Ecker

Comment: I don't know that I have a clear enough view of how the pieces of your project fit together to understand what the issue is. I also don't know if creating new hooks at the ```UserProfile``` and ```UserCard``` level work. I would think you'd need to access them from your context directly like ```appState.setUser({...}``` or ```appState.currentUser.picture``` currently it seems you're just keeping a local copy rather than using the context values directly.

Comment: Check oout my new post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66879342/user-upload-profile-picture-have-to-log-out-and-log-back-in-to-make-the-image-ch. Maybe it more clear

Comment: If you able to help. I can share it with you on zoom